# General approach to puzzles such as the "$6$ books puzzle"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Six different books $(A,B,C,D,E,F)$ of identical size are stacked as in the figure.
[image: six-books]

We know

$A$ and $D$ are not touching.

$E$ is between two books which are both vertical or both horizontal.

$C$ touches exactly two books.

$A$ and $F$ touch.

Question:

If in addition we know

$E$ and $F$ touch along their cover (long side), how many books will have their positions known?

Moreover, is there a general approach to such questions? I did not see how to use adjacency matrix to much benefit.

Comment: thanks for that puzzle :-)

Comment: Is it view from the side or from the top? (not that it matters, but it bugs me)

Comment: if you want a boring that-always-works-approach this smells like adjacency matrices could be worth a try.

Comment: @user2345215  Let's say it is from side as in a bookshelf.

Comment: me no see no bookshelf, bro! i think someone's trying to fool us here.... >:-(

Comment: I wanted to describe how to solve this with Prolog, but as I'm currently learning it I was not able to present you a working piece of code. However, I've asked this question: [How can I solve the '6 books' puzzle with Prolog?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22199085/562769). Prolog might be a quite general way to solve these kinds of puzzles.

Comment: @moose Very interesting. I was wondering how to convert such problems to a set of equations. I did not know there are programming languages for approaching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puzzles like this are usually intended to be solved by hand.

The first clue about $E$ says it is book $2$ or $5$. 
$C$ can be $2,4$ or $6$.
The only book we can be sure of is $D$ in position $1$. It can't be $E$ or $C$. If it is $A$, we must have $F$ in $2$, which contradicts the information on $E$. If it is $F$, it can't touch both $E$ and $A$. If it is $B$, and $EF$ are next to it, either $AD$ touch or $C$ has no home.  If it is $B$ and $EF$ are horizontal, then $A$ has to touch $D$.
To show that is all, we can display two choices for the others: $123456$ can be $DEFCAB$ or $DBAFEC$.

Comment: I don't understand why you say E has to be 2. Isn't this a possible configuration: D=1. B=2. A=3. C=4. E=5. F=6?

Comment: @Francisco:  I see what you mean.  Thinking

Comment: The only one I could fix is D=1.

Comment: @Francisco:  I agree with you.  See my edit

Comment: Good answer! Now the question is: is it possible to fix the position of all books by adding only one more constrain? I thought of "B and F don't touch" but this doesn't seem to be enough. This is a good problem indeed!

Comment: @Francisco:  A in 4 (or 6) seems to work.  It forces EF to 23, then C to 6